# Beware! Beware!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

What are, famously...

> Ebon, sienna
>   High, low
>   Within, without, ubiquitous
>   Distant, close
>   Absent, present
>   Swift and slippery, not to be trusted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mysterious things in question are

> [Heffalumps and Woozles](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Heffalumps_and_Woozles), from Disney's version of Winnie-the-Pooh.

More precisely,

> They're black, they're brown, they're up, they're down
>  They're in, they're out, they're all about
>  They're far, they're near, they're gone, they're here
>  They're quick and slick, they're insincere
>  Beware, beware
>  Be a very wary bear

Incidentally, "famously" is overstating it, at least so far as my state of knowledge goes. I had never encountered

> the song in question (being unfamiliar with Disney-Pooh) but noticed the brown/down and near/here rhymes and went a-googling (first guesses: nursery rhyme, Dr Seuss, of course no luck with either; but putting in "black brown up down far near there here lyrics" did the trick.)

Comment: **Winnie the Pooh and the Blustery Day** won an Oscar, bro, that's famous enough for me (my watching a VHS of it over and over as a kid has nothing to do with it).  But good job on finding it without knowing what the heck I was talking about!

Comment: @Exal That's the power of Google for ya

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't watch that movie and I know it has been answered but a rough answer could be

> Rock mountains

Because

Ebon sienna

> Their colour

High low

> Their height

Within without ubiquitous

> Rocks are almost every where on the earth inside and outside

Distant close

> Many meanings . It might be distance.

Absent present.

> In some area they are present and other not

Swift slippery

> Swift can be there slope and slippery sure they are

Not to be trusted

> Accidents happen on mountains